# Mesh tape between wall and concrete substrate

Tags: tile

My basement bathroom has a concrete floor substrate, on which I will be installing and also have a baseboard of stone tile. Some of the wall meeting the floor will be tile (currently cementboard)

[image]

and some regular drywall but even the drywall will have tile baseboard.

[image]

Should I tape and thinset the corner where the wall currently meets the concrete substrate and should I do it for both the drywall as well as the cementboard, because of the tile baseboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Don't tape the floor to the wall anywhere.

Install the floor first and then install the wall tile.

Comment: Is that to keep water from  going into drywall air cap?

Comment: @RobertMoody it looks nicer to have the transition to be a grout line on the bottom of the wall where you can't see it and any mistakes are hidden, rather than a grout line on the floor that's impossible to make look even and it's easier to see if it's done wrong.

Comment: Ok  get that so you get level start,and down low wont see it.